# Docker run mounting volumes but docker inspect has volumes as null

Tags: docker, mount, volumes

My issue is regarding a docker run command I have created which is running to completion and creating the service however it has mount/volume issues. I am running the following command:

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped --log-driver json-file --log-opt max-file="3" --log-opt max-size="15m" -m 2.875g --cpu-shares=230 --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 --ulimit memlock=-1:-1 --group-add="elasticsearch"  --user="elasticsearch" --net="host" -p 192.168.56.103:9200:9200 -p 192.168.56.103:9300:9300 -v /var/qpackage/elasticsearch/repo:/usr/share/elasticsearch/repo:rw -v /etc/qpackage/elasticsearch/conf/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:rw -v /var/qpackage/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw -v /etc/qpackage/elasticsearch/conf/jvm.options:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options:rw -e "SERVICE_9200_NAME=elasticsearch" -e "SERVICE_9300_NAME=elasticsearch-node" --name elasticsearch-1_log_elasticsearch cp-elasticsearch:7.1.ox
```

And it seems to run perfectly fine. When I do a `docker inspect` however I notice whilst the volumes are I have placed in the command are being mounted and the binds correct the inspect also shows me that Volumes are null. This is incorrect behaviour. The volumes are supposed to shown.

**Current Result**

```
"Volumes": null,
```

**Expected Result**

```
"Volumes": {
                "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml": {},
                "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options": {},
                "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data": {},
                "/usr/share/elasticsearch/repo": {}
            },
```

What could I be doing wrong?

**Full Docker Inspect**

```
[root@localhost tmp]# docker inspect elasticsearch-1_log_elasticsearch
[
    {
        "Id": "be782ca624a468e30dd8c79748ef5406781134c3b6f93450b3b3f425af701301",
        "Created": "2019-11-18T21:48:34.243146943Z",
        "Path": "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "eswrapper"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 18111,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-11-18T21:48:34.645908733Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:6e4f392617213267be91ed63bcd83a425425ed825cf0ab1f346d55375e48d91b",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/qpackage/docker/containers/be782ca624a468e30dd8c79748ef5406781134c3b6f93450b3b3f425af701301/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/qpackage/docker/containers/be782ca624a468e30dd8c79748ef5406781134c3b6f93450b3b3f425af701301/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/qpackage/docker/containers/be782ca624a468e30dd8c79748ef5406781134c3b6f93450b3b3f425af701301/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/qpackage/docker/containers/be782ca624a468e30dd8c79748ef5406781134c3b6f93450b3b3f425af701301/be782ca624a468e30dd8c79748ef5406781134c3b6f93450b3b3f425af701301-json.log",
        "Name": "/elasticsearch-1_log_elasticsearch",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/etc/qpackage/elasticsearch/conf/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml",
                "/var/qpackage/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data",
                "/etc/qpackage/elasticsearch/conf/jvm.options:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options",
                "/var/qpackage/elasticsearch/repo:/usr/share/elasticsearch/repo"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {
                    "max-file": "3",
                    "max-size": "15m"
                }
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": {
                "9200/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "192.168.56.103",
                        "HostPort": "9200"
                    }
                ],
                "9300/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "192.168.56.103",
                        "HostPort": "9300"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "unless-stopped",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": [
                "elasticsearch"
            ],
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 230,
            "Memory": 3087007744,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 6174015488,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": [
                {
                    "Name": "nofile",
                    "Hard": 262144,
                    "Soft": 262144
                },
                {
                    "Name": "memlock",
                    "Hard": -1,
                    "Soft": -1
                }
            ],
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/qpackage/docker/overlay2/f23fc0453e6ef6309612864951ffa3d279dd1197a9f2cb5e27fb7884c16eba69-init/diff:/var/qpackage/docker/overlay2/cc295c456ff0d7a6e33e62578915d4b2dfaec5778e3c7c95a15862333f2ddc87/diff:/var/qpackage/docker/overlay2/baa3e9c814aa237120bbd1668a8dfec75444e3d44ec46afdaf818b03d0584bb6/diff:/var/qpackage/docker/overlay2/ac48075afe8ae211844285573419bc9e08b92b89877deca5b10eed7f071fd43c/diff:/var/qpackage/docker/overlay2/b1395bb3de16587b201eceaa1468951c1224fcd37d3e49ff012954fa0e621836/diff:/var/qpackage/docker/overlay2/a2ac251b148df5aba19addea36ecd85b7b45a5590740684ae928586f55a93fdc/diff:/var/qpackage/docker/overlay2/0cb5d6a8739367e5eab2b071f5ec3f4cb6e4d62b4d94a4919635ec05e7a6198f/diff:/var/qpackage/docker/overlay2/67657868ee478d3cb47093c67d1824eb873e2628840486bb63aef7eee29652bd/diff:/var/qpackage/docker/overlay2/108ed1526882b849cf3991c8177b7389e84da4b9a48828f43b08351b6c69ddf0/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/qpackage/docker/overlay2/f23fc0453e6ef6309612864951ffa3d279dd1197a9f2cb5e27fb7884c16eba69/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/qpackage/docker/overlay2/f23fc0453e6ef6309612864951ffa3d279dd1197a9f2cb5e27fb7884c16eba69/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/qpackage/docker/overlay2/f23fc0453e6ef6309612864951ffa3d279dd1197a9f2cb5e27fb7884c16eba69/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/etc/qpackage/elasticsearch/conf/elasticsearch.yml",
                "Destination": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/var/qpackage/elasticsearch/data",
                "Destination": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/etc/qpackage/elasticsearch/conf/jvm.options",
                "Destination": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/var/qpackage/elasticsearch/repo",
                "Destination": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/repo",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "elasticsearch",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "9200/tcp": {},
                "9300/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "SERVICE_9200_NAME=elasticsearch",
                "SERVICE_9300_NAME=elasticsearch-node",
                "PATH=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "ELASTIC_CONTAINER=true"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "eswrapper"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "cp-elasticsearch:7.1.ox",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/usr/share/elasticsearch",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "license": "Elastic License",
                "org.label-schema.build-date": "20190305",
                "org.label-schema.license": "GPLv2",
                "org.label-schema.name": "elasticsearch",
                "org.label-schema.schema-version": "1.0",
                "org.label-schema.url": "https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch",
                "org.label-schema.vcs-url": "https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch",
                "org.label-schema.vendor": "Elastic",
                "org.label-schema.version": "7.1.0"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "087bbb8b4469e2a5ac35aee69b62c7e8db8eb6bc16acf529d437f4777586cbac",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "047831b94cd687f5e144568ac52925897a8b2f5ee21c9af7286c0afe39b3ee03",
                    "EndpointID": "1a2e3b823fc5d28b4ddb4ccda9c005fff2f15d439d7f65ec27fbe2587f5395d1",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running a command derived from an ansible configuration we have created using Ansible's docker_container module. What we didn't realise was that ansible's volumes declaration created not only the bind mountings but also anonymous volumes to go with them. As a result the above `docker run` that we created was not the same since it didn't create the volumes but simply created the bind mountings. Simply adding anonymous volumes declarations like `-v /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml` corrected the issue.