# docker run not responding to command-line "--mount" and "--name" options

Tags: docker

My question might look like a repeat of [Docker run mounting volumes but docker inspect has volumes as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961646/docker-run-mounting-volumes-but-docker-inspect-has-volumes-as-null), but it does not address my situation. I run a command like

```
docker run -d my-image --name my-name -v /host/path:/container/path
```

The container starts without complaint. But when I run `docker inspect` it shows

```
"Volumes": null
...
"Name": "/blissful_napier",
```

So it does not seem to respond to any of the command-line options I passed.

The answer to the linked question has something to do with anonymous volumes. I don't think this is related to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All docker flags must be specified before the image name:

```
$ docker run -d --name my-name -v /host/path:/container/path my-image
```

everything that comes after the image name is passed to the entrypoint of the image.